# Calculating the sum of multiple angles

Tags: geometry

The points $D$ and $E$ divide the side $AB$ of an equilateral triangle in three equal parts, such that $D$ is inbetween $A$ and $E$. The point $F$ is on $[BC]$ such that $CF=AD$.
Calculate $\widehat{CDF}+\widehat{CEF}$

I've tried to apply the law of cosinus multiple times, but that seems like a bad proof... Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

We see that $\triangle{DFB}$ is an equilateral triangle and $\triangle{CDE}$ is an isosceles triangle.

Since $\angle{FEB}=90^\circ$, we get
$$\angle{DCE}=180^\circ-2\angle{CED}=180^\circ-2(90^\circ-\angle{CEF})=2\angle{CEF}$$
So, letting $G$ be the intersection point of $CE$ with $DF$ where $\angle{GFE}=30^\circ$, we get
$$\angle{GCD}+\angle{GDC}=\angle{GFE}+\angle{GEF},$$
from which we get
$$\angle{CDF}+\angle{CEF}=\color{red}{30^\circ}$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose point $G$ on $AC$ such that $CG = CF$. By the symmetry, $\widehat{CEF} = \widehat{CDG}$. So, the sum you're looking for is actually the angle $\widehat{GDF}$. At this point, you gotta realize $GF = AD$, and $GF$ is parallel to $AB$, thus, $ADFG$ is a parallelogram. As $\frac{AG}{AD} =2$, $\widehat{GDA} = 90^\circ$. Giving, $\widehat{GDF} = 30^\circ$.

Comment: Isn't the conclusion wrong? I think it should be $30\circ$

Comment: @Didoua Ooops, you're right. It was a typo. Edited it.